# Why my tensorflow(keras) model raised the error, ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable:?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have been trying to make model use the my customed loss function named Confusion_mat_loss. But I had a problem.
I constructed model and this is my model:

```
    def Generate_model(self, Batch_first=False, Batch_last=False):
        Input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input( batch_shape=(None, 16, 24, 24, 24), name='Input_layer')

        # Make Mdoel -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if Batch_first:
            Batch_normal = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(Input_layer)
            conv_layer1  = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=80, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu',
                                                  data_format='channels_first')(Batch_normal)
            # Max_pooling  = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling3D( pool_size=(2, 2, 2), data_format='channels_first')(conv_layer1)

            conv_layer2  = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=100, kernel_size=(2, 2, 2), activation='relu',
                                                  data_format='channels_first')(conv_layer1)
            Max_pooling  = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling3D( pool_size=(2, 2, 2), data_format='channels_first')(conv_layer2)

            GloMax_pool  = tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPool3D(data_format='channels_first')(Max_pooling)

        elif Batch_last:
            conv_layer1  = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=80, kernel_size=(2, 2, 2), activation='relu',
                                                 data_format='channels_first')(Input_layer)
            # Max_pooling  = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling3D( pool_size=(2, 2, 2), data_format='channels_first')(conv_layer1)

            conv_layer2  = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(filters=100, kernel_size=(2, 2, 2), activation='relu',
                                                 data_format='channels_first')(conv_layer1)
            Max_pooling  = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling3D( pool_size=(2, 2, 2), data_format='channels_first')(conv_layer2)

            Batch_normal = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(Max_pooling)
            GloMax_pool  = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAvgPool3D(data_format='channels_first')(Batch_normal)

        Dense_layer  = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=2 ** 7, activation='relu')(GloMax_pool)
        Output_layer = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU()(Dense_layer)
        Output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(Output_layer)


        self.model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=Input_layer, outputs=Output_layer)
        self.model.summary()
```

with my model, I wanted to use the customed loss function and this is my loss funtion.

```
def Confusion_mat_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = K.cast(y_true, dtype='float32',)
    y_true = K.squeeze(y_true, axis=1)

    y_pred = K.cast(y_pred, dtype='float32',)
    y_pred = K.squeeze(y_pred, axis=1)
    Con_matrix = tf.math.confusion_matrix(labels=y_true, predictions=y_pred, num_classes=2)

    TP = Con_matrix[0, 0]; TN = Con_matrix[0, 1]; FP = Con_matrix[1, 0]; FN = Con_matrix[1, 1]
    fallout = FP / (FP + TN)
    print(fallout)

    return fallout
```

When I tried to train the model with this code:

```
self.model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=Confusion_mat_loss, metrics=[Confusion_mat_loss,])
self.model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, epochs=1, batch_size=3, validation_split=0.2, verbose=False)
```

However, I have met the Error:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: 
['batch_normalization/gamma:0', 'batch_normalization/beta:0', 'conv3d/kernel:0', 'conv3d/bias:0', 'conv3d_1/kernel:0', 'conv3d_1/bias:0', 'dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0', 'dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0'].
```

I don' t know what I missed.. Any idea on to what caused this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Elements in confusion matrix you used in the loss function are not differentiable. That's why the error's raised.

Comment: When I wanted to use the Confusion matrix, how to I construct the loss function? Is it not possible?

Comment: Please edit your question so that what you want is understood. Currently, it's difficult to comprehend what you need.

Comment: Because I want to make loss function with the confusion matrix used, Is there any other pathway?

Comment: I don't think this is easily doable. Usually NNs use `rmse` `categorical_crossentropy` etc as the loss. Why do you want to use the confusion matrix?

Comment: Because the confusion matrix is used to metric in my field, so I find the way to use the confusion matrix.